# php cant get imap_search working

Tags: php, email, imap

I am using the IMAP_SEARCH to look for emails sent by someone using the following

```
$uids = imap_search($mbox,'FROM "neil.xxx@domain.com"', SE_UID);
```

if the email headers FROM just contains

```
neil.xxx@domain.com
```

then i get the UID number for that email, however if the email headers FROM contains the contact name and the email address like this.

```
Neil <neil.xxx@domain.com>
```

then i get nothing back at all, but if i was to use this

```
$uids = imap_search($mbox,'FROM "neil"', SE_UID);
```

Then i get the UID number.

My issue is why cant i just provide the email address and get the UID regardless

Comment: Because your server has a bad implementation of IMAP SEARCH?  What is your server software?

Comment: @max, i did read on a few sites this could be the issue however the email is hosted with Microsoft office 365, which then surprised me so wondered if it was something else.